# Xcode 15 locking up my app from running: 1 log/signpost messages lost due to high rates in live mode recording?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

This just started today in Xcode 15. I haven't added any new logs or print statements but when I build and run on my iPhone 14 Pro, I tap on a view in my app, the console is printing:

> 1 log/signpost messages lost due to high rates in live mode recording. To guarantee delivery of all logs, set IDELogRedirectionPolicy to oslogToStdio in the environment of the executable.

tons of times. When I build and run the exact same code on my iPhone 13 mini, it doesn't do it?

Comment: Well, it turned out to be one of those Apple bugs that just isn't communicated well.  I'm not 100% sure what it was, but I think I added an additional piece of logic that made the overall processing load in the app too high which for some reason generated this console log and the freeze.  I removed the additional logic and it went away.

Comment: do you have any reference/info on the Apple bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same thing, but only when I ran my app on a physical device. I couldn't debug anymore because my debug area in XCode kept on showing these messages.

So I did what the log message said and added the environment variable `IDELogRedirectionPolicy` with value `oslogToStdio` to the environment of the executable. Now I don't see these messages anymore in my debug area.

Comment: This solution removes the ability to sort and filter logged messages in Xcode 15, all logs lose their colored metadata info and look equal

Comment: If you keep this environment variable indefinitely, does this apply to 'Release' configuration builds as well?

Answer (score 13):

To set the environment variable as the log output suggests, go to 'Edit Scheme...', on the left column 'Run Debug' should be highlighted, select the 'Arguments' tab, under the 'Environment Variables' click the the plus (+) sign, under name fill in *IDELogRedirectionPolicy*, under value fill in *oslogToStdio*

Answer (score 5):

Follow the below steps

Open **Edit Schema**

[image]

Then follow the below screenshot and update the text `IDELogRedirectionPolicy` and  `oslogToStdio`

[image]